# Show that $ABCD$ has an incircle if and only if $\frac {1}{PE} + \frac {1}{PG} = \frac {1}{PF} +\frac {1}{PH}$

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral.Let the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect in $P$.Let $PE,PF,PG,PH$ be the altitudes from $P$ onto the sides $AB,BC,CD$ and $DA$ respectively.Show that $ABCD$ has an incircle if and only if

> $\frac {1}{PE} + \frac {1}{PG} = \frac {1}{PF} +\frac {1}{PH}$

Answer (score 0):

**Source**: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?u=166324&b=103587

Let me denote the distances $PE,PF,PG,PH$ as $h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4$. Let $AB=a,BC=b,CD,c,DA=d$

$\frac{h_1}{h_4}=\frac{d(C,AB)}{d(C,AD)}=\frac{b \sin B}{c \sin D}$

$\frac{h_1}{h_2}=\frac{d(D,AB)}{d(D,BC)}=\frac{d \sin A}{c \sin C}$

$\frac{h_1}{h_3}=\frac{h_1}{h_2} \cdot \frac{h_2}{h_3} = \frac{d \sin A}{c \sin C} \cdot \frac{d(A,BC)}{d(A,CD)}=\frac{d \sin A*a \ sin B}{c \sin C*d \sin D}$

Therefore, we get

$\frac{1}{h_1}+\frac{1}{h_3}=\frac{1}{h_2}+\frac{1}{h_4}$

$\iff 1+\frac{h_1}{h_3}=\frac{h_1}{h_2}+\frac{h_1}{h_4}$

$\iff 1+\frac{d \sin A \cdot a \sin B}{c \sin C \cdot d \sin D}=\frac{d \sin A}{c \sin C}+\frac{b \sin B}{c \sin D}$

$\iff a \sin A \sin B+ c \sin C \sin D=b \sin B \sin C+ d \sin D \sin A (\star)$

For the 'if' part, let r be the inradius of ABCD. Then, we get

$a=r \left( \cot \frac{A}{2} + \cot \frac{B}{2} \right) = r \frac{\sin \frac{A+B}{2}}{\sin \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2}}$

$
\implies a \sin A \sin B = 4r \cos \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{A+B}{2}$

$=4r \cos \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C+D}{2}$

$= 4r \cos \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{B}{2} \cos \frac{C}{2} \cos \frac{D}{2} \left( \tan \frac{C}{2} + \tan \frac{D}{2} \right)$

$= 4r \gamma \left( \tan \frac{C}{2} + \tan \frac{D}{2} \right)$

$where  \gamma=\cos \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{B}{2} \cos \frac{C}{2} \cos \frac{D}{2}$.

Analogously, $b \sin B \sin C = 4r \gamma \left( \tan \frac{D}{2} + \tan \frac{A}{2} \right)$

$c \sin C \sin D = 4r \gamma \left( \tan \frac{A}{2} + \tan \frac{B}{2} \right)$

$d \sin D \sin A = 4r \gamma \left( \tan \frac{B}{2} + \tan \frac{C}{2} \right)$

It is now easily seen that both sides of equation $(\star)$ are equal to $4r \gamma \left( \tan \frac{A}{2} + \tan \frac {B}{2} + \tan \frac{C}{2} + \tan \frac{D}{2} \right)$, hence the proof of the 'if' part is complete.

For the 'only if' part. Suppose first that in ABCD, both pairs of opposite sides are parallel. Then, the hypothesis, $a \sin A \sin B+ c \sin C \sin D=b \sin B \sin C+ d \sin D \sin A$ reduces to $a+c=b+d$ so ABCD becomes a rhombus and it obviously has an incircle. So we'll assume that ABCD has atleast one pair of nonparallel opposite sides, WLOG, they are AD and BC. Assume that ABCD is not tangential. There exists a circle $\Gamma$ touching segments $DA,AB,BC$. Because of our assumption, this circle does not touch side CD. Construct a parallel to CD which is tangent to the circle, and meeting BC,AD at C',D' respectively. Let BC' = b', C'D'=c' and D'A=d'. Since quadrilateral ABC'D' is tangential, we have

$a \sin A \sin B+ c' \sin C \sin D=b' \sin B \sin C+ d' \sin D \sin A$

Along with the equation,

$a \sin A \sin B+ c \sin C \sin D=b \sin B \sin C+ d \sin D \sin A$

we get

$(CD - C'D') \sin C \sin D = C'C \sin B \sin C + D'D \sin D \sin A$

If $\Gamma$ intersects the segment CD, then note that $C'C$ and $D'D$ are negative, while $CD-C'D' $is positive, contradiction. If $\Gamma$ does not intersect the segment $CD$, then $C'C$ and $D'DD'D$ are positive, while $CD - C'D'$ is negative, again a contradiction. Thus, we conclude that $\Gamma$ is tangent to $CD$ and hence, $ABCD$ is tangential.

Comment: Yes I appeared, but I wasn't able to solve it then(and gave a lot of time to this question), but finally solved it with a little help. Please edit if you find some mistakes .

Comment: I was able to do No.  3,4,6 but I know I won't get selected. I have done some silly mistake in 2 of them. What about you?

Comment: Yep, 546 is correct. I used the 'desi' combinations method taught in class 11 and is perfect. If I get time, I will post the solution on your question. By the way, why is no one up voting my solution. This is my first big solution with a lot of hard work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20834/discussion-between-snehil-sinha-and-garvil-singhal).

Comment: @GarvilSinghal, atleast attach the source. 

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?u=166324&b=103587

What hardwork you did? -_-

Comment: This solutions was told to me by a friend on email. (I told him where I was stuck). He replied me with exactly this. I did not know it was taken from aops. Sorry from my side.

Comment: You said " This is my first big solution with lot of hardwork". 
There is NO CHANGE from that blog post.

Comment: That's not my fault. Yes, I wanted to take credit of my friend's answer, but I didn't know he would cheat the solution.(he has a brilliant mind). If you want I can give you his email.

Comment: Removed my vote. This seems important though http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2009volume9/FG200910.pdf .. I wonder how a question with such long solution got to INMO :O

Comment: this result is even on wikepedia!